# Cascade Update on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edit

I would like to update my account object which has child `AccountProfile` but I'm getting an exception saying that attaching entity failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value...

I would like to know how I could update these entities especially `AccountProfile` since I can add/remove `Beneficiary` objects from its list. Is it possible to do something like a cascade update? or create a method which handles these kinds of entity updates.

Account Class:

```
Public class Account(){
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public virtual AccountProfile Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

AccountProfile Class:

```
public class AccountProfile
{
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Beneficiary> Beneficiaries { get; set; }
}
```

Beneficiary Class:

```
Public Class Beneficiary()
{
    public int BeneficiaryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Edit Method:

```
   public void Edit(Account account)
    {
        _context.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();           
    }
```

Comment: You can override `SaveChanges()` method in your `DbContext` class to perform custom cascade update to all related entities. Can you provide exception details related to dupe PK values as stated in your question?

Comment: I'm getting an `InvalidOperationException` in `EntityFramework.dll` stating Attaching an entity of type X failed. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values...

Comment: Probably the culprit belongs to line `_context.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified`. Somewhere in controller may performing materialization in your model class which includes entity you tried to modify (better to show where `Edit` method called into). Try using `_context.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Detached` before `Modified` as first attempt.